# Open, Write and read RS232 port Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile-applications, industry-4.0, android-things, data-portability

I have to do a project with an industrial android screen that consists among other things to open, write and read a serial port. I clarify that my device has rs232 ports (I think that the classic libraries do not serve me to communicate by opening USB).

I have tried with different libraries to open the ports and I could not achieve it. Also I need to set parity, stop bit, data bits and speed. I was able to get the port name from the screen, it is /dev/ttyS1. How to achieve this? Or what library can I use?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194427/6495973) on our sister site stackoverflow

Comment: @anonymous2 I think the other answer to that question (not the accepted one) is probably more suitable.